# libcurl http get request in json format

Tags: c, http, curl, get, libcurl

Is there a way to send a HTTP get request using libcurl in JSON format?

My current request is

`curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9200/_search?q=tag:warcraft")`

using libcurl. It's equivalent in curl is

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_all/tweet/_search?q=tag:warcraft
```

I would like to send the following curl request (in json format) using libcurl.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_search -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "tag": "warcraft" }
    }
}'
```

I would like to know the equivalent libcurl code to send the above request. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_data_encoded_as_string);
```

The -d option is used for POST method. From the curl man page

> -d, --data  Sends the specified data in a POST request to the
>   HTTP server

If you need to send more data that can not fit in a query string you have to use POST method

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)

> As part of a GET request, some data can be passed within the URI's
>   query string, specifying for example search terms, date ranges, or
>   other information that defines the query. As part of a POST request,
>   an arbitrary amount of data of any type can be sent to the server in a
>   request message body.

If you strictly have to use GET (?) form your url in such a way to put your json data in the query string itself.

```
query_string = "q=" + json_encoded_to_str
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9200/_search?" + query_string)
```

Comment: I thought that CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS are relevant to http post request. I need something for HTTP GET request.

Comment: IMO, not a good idea. But still achievable. Answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks. I took your advice on using POST method and got it to work. I followed this code skeleton. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html

Comment: @dineshsriram nice! Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Following kalyan's advice, this is the code I ended up with. Posting this for completion.

```
int main() {

     CURL *curl_handle;     
     CURLcode res;

    static const char *postthis="{\"query\":{\"term\":{\tag\":\"warcraft\"}}}";
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl_handle) {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9200/_search");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postthis);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(postthis));
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, stdout);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, stdout);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
                  fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                                        curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
        return 0;
    }
}
```