# How to sendi HTTP request and parse JSON response in TIZEN watch using Native?

Tags: json, http, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

Hi I'am new to Tizen Development and would like to explore functions/features like what I used in android development. So I want to learn how to post/get HTTP and parse the json response from the URL using Native Tizen watch. Can anyone help me or point me to some tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `curl` . Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597257/calling-a-json-webservice-from-c-using-curl-and-json-c/26598651) using:

Add these headers

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <net_connection.h>
```

And implement like this

```
    /* Initialize CURL */ 
    CURL *curlHandler = curl_easy_init();


    connection_h connection;

    int conn_err;
    conn_err = connection_create(&connection);
    if (conn_err != CONNECTION_ERROR_NONE) {
        /* Error handling */
        return false;
    }

    if(curlHandler) {
      /* Set CURL parameters */
      curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.yoururl.com");
      curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_easy_setopt(curlHandler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  jObj);

      /* Perform the request */ 
      CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curlHandler);

      /* Check for errors */ 
      if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "CURL failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

      /* Clean up */ 
      curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandler);
      json_object_object_del(jObj, "name");
      connection_destroy(connection);
      free(jObj);
  }
```

You can also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236479/libcurl-http-get-request-in-json-format) and this [link](https://gist.github.com/leprechau/e6b8fef41a153218e1f4).

Tutorial: [This](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html)

Comment: Hi I forgot to include this in the question. I will be using this in tizen watch

Comment: Idea is same. Just use this code in your Tizen gear app.

Comment: when using #include <json-c/json.h>, i got "fatal error: 'json-c/json.h' file not found".

Comment: Hi thanks for an update. Although I figure out already how to post data using curl. Now I'm figuring out how to parse the JSON return of my API.

Comment: And what was your question on this thread ? did you get this ?

Comment: The question was how to post data and parse the json response. Yes I got this thanks for the updated answer. I'm new to curl and just have a basic knowledge in C.

Comment: Check this thread 
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/native-application-development/how-tizen-native-app-get-and-parse-json-data-google-map-api?langswitch=ko